# E4 contribute with a shared element

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

My application is built from multiple plugins/model fragments. I am trying to contribute with a shared element (a part) in one of my fragments. I don't have access to the main e4xmi file (the one that contains the Trimmed Window) so it has to be done within my fragment. Any way I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment.e4xmi just add a Model Fragment specifying the id of the parent Trimmed Window as the  'Extended Element ID' and 'sharedElements' as the 'Feature Name'. Add your part to the

Something like:
[image: model fragment]

Comment: I entered the id of parent like you said but i can't add anything. the combo box list is empty. I also tried importing the window from "Imports" tab but it doesn't find it. My trimmed window is in another plugin which is added to the dependencies. Do you know how can I import the window from it ?